# Mockito test failure - arguments (Mongo DBObjects) are different (are not!)

Tags: java, mongodb, mockito

### EDIT: the question advanced into a more specific one below.

A test doesn't pass, this failure occurs:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
declColl.find(
    { "declensions" : { "$in" : [ "testtest"]}}
);
-> at cz.xxx.CzechMongoWordDeclensionsRetrieverTest.getLemmaTest(CzechMongoWordDeclensionsRetrieverTest.java:63)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
declColl.find(
    { "declensions" : { "$in" : [ "testtest"]}}
);
```

You can see what my problem is immediately from the output of the failure. There is no difference. The `toString` method might be deceiving, maybe `equals` method returns `false` for the `DBObject`s... as I state below, I am not sure how to check this, but checking equality of two "queryBuilt" same `DBObject`s returned `true`.

The test is short and looks like this:

```
@InjectMocks
private CzechMongoWordDeclensionsRetriever declRetriever;
@Mock
private DBCollection declColl;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Object[] criteria = new String[1];
    criteria[0] = "testtest";

    //mocks init
    DBCursor cur = mock(DBCursor.class);
    DBObject queryObj = QueryBuilder.start("declensions").in(criteria).get();
    when(declColl.find(queryObj)).thenReturn(cur);
    when(cur.size()).thenReturn(1);
    when(cur.next()).thenReturn(new BasicDBObject("lemma", "testtest"));
}

@Test
public void getLemmaTest() {
    Object[] criteria = new String[1];
    criteria[0] = "testtest";
    DBObject queryObj = QueryBuilder.start("declensions").in(criteria).get();

    String toTest = "testtest";
    String testResult = declRetriever.getLemma(toTest);

    verify(declColl).find(queryObj);
}
```

with the getLemma method like this:

```
public String getLemma(String word) {
        criteria[0] = word;
        DBObject lemmaObj = QueryBuilder.start("declensions").in(criteria).get();
        DBCursor cursor = declColl.find(lemmaObj);

        if(cursor == null)     return null;
        if(cursor.size() > 1)  return null; 
        if(cursor.size() == 0) return null; 

        return (String) cursor.next().get("lemma");
    }
```

The code doesn't even get lower than to `if(cursor == null)` part, since the stub is not working. I created two distinct `DBObject`s by running the `QueryBuilder` twice and then checked if they are equal (I don't know how the implementation of `equals` Mongo `DBObject` lookslike - edit: compares map entries).

I have no clue, why the failure occurs.

### EDIT: (should this be a new question?)

I have tried Biju Kunjummen's answer and it did not help at first, but I tried this:

```
    Object[] criteria = new String[1];
    criteria[0] = "testtest";
    DBObject queryObj = QueryBuilder.start("declensions").in(criteria).get();
    Object[] criteria2 = new String[1];
    criteria2[0] = "testtest";
    DBObject queryObj2 = QueryBuilder.start("declensions").in(criteria).get();
    assertTrue(queryObj.equals(queryObj2));
```

and the assert fails. So I can see the problem is not with Mockito, but the DBObjects do not match, even though they should. To me, semantically the queries are equal. (answered below): it seems like, if a `Map.entry` has an `Object[]` as a value which has the same contents as the compared `Object[]` `equals` goes `false`, if the `Object[]` is not the same reference as the compared one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So: `verify` method was checking, if I was using the same `queryObj` as attribute. Since it used `equals` and since `DBObject` is compared by the mapped values via `Map` `equals` method, it checked the equality of `Map` `entry`s. And I believe, that it did not compare the two `Object[]` arrays for it's contents, but checked the references and found them not matching. Thus equality was `false` and `verify` said that it was expecting different parameter.

I replaced the use of `Object[]` with `List<>` and now the `verify` method is happy - it passes.

The test was still not working, but it was for completely different reasons, which I (might) describe in a different question: //will post here, if I find looking for an answer important enough.

Anyways, the test now works ok like this:

```
@Test
public void getLemmaTest() {

    //... now I use List<String> instead of Object[]. declColl is already stubbed 
    // to return something, when a find(queryObj) is called.
    List<String> criteriaColl = new ArrayList<>();
    criteriaColl.add("testtest");
    DBObject queryObj = QueryBuilder.start("declensions").in(criteriaColl).get();

    String expResult = "testtest";
    String toTest = "testtest";
    String testResult = declRetriever.getLemma(toTest);

    verify(declColl).find(queryObj);
    assertEquals(expResult, testResult);  
}
```

and the implementation of getLemma.

```
public String getLemma(String word) {
    criteria.set(0, word);
    DBObject lemmaObj = QueryBuilder.start("declensions").in(criteria).get();
    DBCursor cursor = declColl.find(lemmaObj);
    if(cursor == null)      return null;
    if(cursor.size() > 1)   return null;
    if(cursor.size() == 0)  return null;
    return (String) cursor.next().get("lemma");
}
```

I could not use

```
criteria.add(word);
//....
criteria.remove(0);
```

for unknown reasons, which I (might) ask in the next question. (I will post the link here, if I create the question)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because your `DBObject.equals`(and hashcode) is not correctly implemented, a quick way to check it would be to try this:

```
DBObject queryObj1 = QueryBuilder.start("declensions").in(criteria).get();
DBObject queryObj2 = QueryBuilder.start("declensions").in(criteria).get();

assertTrue(queryObj1.equals(queryObj2))
```

This would likely fail, and this is the reason for the Mock assertion error.

Comment: I done exactly the same thing, but the equals passed ok...  But now that I read it again, I realized, that I should try passing "criteria" again, being equal semantically, but instantiated as different objects. Then it failed. Not sure what to do with it however... Could you address my addition to the question in edited question?

Comment: Hmm..interesting, reading the Mockito documentation, it says that equals should have been sufficient for argument matchers!, would love to see what cleanly works for you.

Comment: Well I copied the code which passes and which fails into this link, if you'd like to see, it's pretty short http://pastebin.com/P72FAsAY